# CASE Statement in where clause using equal to and IN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case-statement, in-clause

```
WHERE CONDITION1='ABC'
AND Status =
    CASE  @Option 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'True'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'False'
            WHEN 3 THEN  NULL
            WHEn 4 THEN **IN ('True', 'False', NULL)**
    END
```

How do I write a query where my first options match directly using `=`  but my last option needs an `IN`

The above query gives error, but I want something similar to it, which I am not able to find out.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: You can't compare directly to NULL like you're trying to in your `IN` statement, since NULL means unknown. You'll have to have a separate statement for that, using `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `CASE` statement can't return a set of values... but this query should give you the same results:

```
WHERE CONDITION1='ABC'
AND Status =
    CASE  
        WHEN 1 THEN 'True'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'False'
        WHEN 3 THEN NULL
        WHEN 4 THEN Status
    END
```

Also, note that unless you have `ANSI_NULLS OFF`, `Status` will never `= NULL`... you would need to use `IS NULL` for this comparison, and you'd need to forgo the `CASE` statement altogether.

Comment: +1 for sneakiness... I like your use of `Status` to encompass all three possible choices. -0.4 for not immediately obvious what the code does. Total: +0.6, rounds up to +1. :-)

Comment: What if status equals something not one of those choices?

Comment: @PinnyM Then it'll try and do the comparison to NULL exactly the same as the case for 3 here.

Comment: @Bridge, my point was that if @Option = 4 and status = 'foo', it will evaluate as a boolean `true`, while the initial pseudo-algorithm would  have been `false`.  It may not be a problem for the OP, but this scenario hasn't been dealt with...

Answer (score 5):

Skip the CASE statement and use OR.  And as per ANSI standard [don't compare with NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004570/why-does-comparing-a-sql-date-variable-to-null-behave-in-this-way/9004627#9004627):

```
WHERE CONDITION1='ABC'
AND ((@Option = 1 AND Status = 'True') OR
     (@Option = 2 AND Status = 'False') OR
     (@Option = 3 AND Status IS NULL) OR
     (@Option = 4 AND (Status IS NULL OR Status IN ('True', 'False'))))
```