# Dynamic where clause based on variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working on a select statement in SQL and am running into issues trying to create a where clause that includes a case statement or an if else statement. I want to select records based on the value of a variable. If the variable is 'True' then only return records from the select statement where a column is null. If the variable is not 'True' then return all records regardless if that columns is null.

Any tips on how to do this?

Below is a simple example of what i am trying to do:

```
declare @option1 as varchar(5)

--This can be True or False so to test i just put the Set option below
set @option1 = 'True'

Select a,b,c,d...
from ...
where d = case when @option1 = 'True' then NULL End
```

This is the part where i do not know what to do. I only need to filter out the records if the variable is 'True' so not sure what to put in the else section of the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't test for `d = NULL` as your CASE statement does because that will always return false since [NULL is not equal to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004570/why-does-comparing-a-sql-date-variable-to-null-behave-in-this-way/9004627#9004627) (unless you set ANSI_NULLS to 'off').

The simplest thing to do would be to change the WHERE clause to this:

```
WHERE @option1 = 'False' OR d IS NULL
```

If you prefer to use a CASE statement for some reason, you can write it like this:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @option1 = 'False' THEN 1 
               WHEN @option1 = 'True' AND d IS NULL THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
          END
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

UPDATE: PinnyM has straightened me out on this. I am leaving my embarrassing logically flawed argument here for the education of the masses. The solution I propose below after "Try this" is certainly still valid, but PinnyM's solutions is by far more elegant and should be used.

> WHERE @option1 = 'False' OR d IS NULL

Will always return all the results given his current select statement (assuming @Option1 is simply a flag parameter passed in).

Try this:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
WHERE 
    -- Returns only rows where d is null (if @Option1 is True)
    (@Option1 = 'True' AND d IS NULL) 
    OR
     -- returns all the rows (if @Option1 is False)
    (@Option1 = 'False')
```

Comment: In the WHERE clause I wrote, if @Option1 is 'True' and d is not NULL, then the record will be excluded.  I'm pretty sure that's precisely what the OP wanted...

Comment: If I understand the OP's question (and it IS up for interpretation!), Option1 is not a field in the table, and therefore the status of Option1 has no effect on the filtering of records. In your proposed WHERE clause, All rows in which d IS NOT NULL will be included no matter the value of Option1, and all rows in which d IS NULL will also always be included. There is no filtering (unless I am missing something silly, which is entirely possible).

Comment: @PinnyM - I believe your second option does the trick though.

Comment: Certainly @Option1 is not a field in the table, but if you add a filter like this: `WHERE 'True' = 'False'`, you will effectively exclude all rows even though no columns were used as part of the where clause.  Try it out and see.  Therefore, the first option works and recommended for its simplicity.

Comment: Whoa. Interesting. I will most definitely try it out and see. Didn't think of it that way (and a little embarrassed for it), but I suspect(Ok, suspect, nothing, I KNOW) you are correct. But I just have to run it myself, kind of like touching the red-hot burner to see if it's really "hot". Nicely done, +1

Comment: Both suggestions worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch for the quick replies and suggestions.