# Where is my banana? (SQL Query NULL issue)

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fruit](
    [RecId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Banana] [int] NULL,
    [TextValue] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

And the following piece of code:

```
DECLARE @FruitInput INT = NULL
SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE Banana = @FruitInput
```

This record is in that table:

```
1|NULL|Hello
```

Why wont my query return this record?

Comment: May be `@FruitInput` is null?

Comment: [NULL does _not_ equal NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004570/why-does-comparing-a-sql-date-variable-to-null-behave-in-this-way/9004627#9004627) - use `IS NULL`

Comment: +1 for question title alone.

Comment: in sql server NULL is considered to be an "Unknown" value. so you really cant compare an Unknown value to any other known value. Thats why we use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL, in other words IS "Unknown" or IS NOT "Unkown".

Comment: You can use `SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Banana INTERSECT SELECT @FruitInput)`

Comment: @MartinSmith that's not correct syntax. `SELECT banana` from where?

Comment: @gvee - From the outer query. Try it! [More details here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith you just wrinkled my brain! I would never have guessed that would work. I don't think I quite understand it yet but I'm definitely going to go play some more! P.S. thanks for the article link

Comment: @gvee - The `FROM` is optional in TSQL. So just like doing `SELECT 1 INTERSECT SELECT 1` except it references a column from the outer query.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think I get it now. You don't have to reference the table explicitly (as it is in *scope* already). I think for clarity I will write this method as `... EXISTS  (SELECT Fruit.Banana INTERSECT SELECT @FruitInput)` going forward.

Comment: Yes, @FruitInput IS NULL, that is the whole thing. The column in my record contains NULL as well, so therefore i was expecting to find that record.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because `Null is undefined`. Null neither equal nor not equal to anything. Please read more on **[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**.

Null values can be checked with `is null` (or `is not null`), or `isnull()` *or* `coalesce()` functions depending on the requirement.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE Banana is null
```

And following query to select `all the records` in case if `@FruitInput is null`:

```
SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE @FruitInput is null or Banana = @FruitInput
```

Comment: But, why can't i do the same query with a variable, which is NULL as well?

Comment: Because you cannot compare null with comparison operators. Please read the [remarks section](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx) on this link.

Comment: Thanks for all the anwers guys. I'll go with this answer, because of the MSDN link, which explained the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

NULL does not equal NULL, use IS NULL for null row checks:

`SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE Banana IS NULL`

In this case because you have NULL in a variable, you can use the ISNULL operator:

`SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE ISNULL(Banana, 0) = ISNULL(@FruitInput, 0)`

This will ensure you can check against whatever value NULL is or otherwise compare 0 to 0 - obviously if you have rows where Banana is NULL and @FruitInput is 0 this will match them, adjust as necessary

(e.g. you can jut use -1 or a string)

`SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE ISNULL(Banana, '') = ISNULL(@FruitInput, '')`

Edit: No you can't because for some reason 0 = '' in SQL....?!

I suppose the way to do it (which might not be that performant, I've not checked the plan) is:

```
select * from Fruit 
where 1 = CASE
    WHEN @FruitInput IS NULL AND banana IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN @FruitInput = banana THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: This will also bring back all `NULL` rows if `0` is passed and vice-versa.

Comment: I did mention that, I've updated with the only way I can think of!

Answer (score 0):

A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE Banana IS Null
```

Answer (score 0):

The value NULL means that the data value for the column is unknown or not available, and a comparison in which one or more of the expressions is NULL yields unknown, so you can't directly compare Banana with null but you should use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Fruit
WHERE Banana = @FruitInput OR COALESCE(Banana, @FruitInput) IS NULL
```

Coalesce will return the first non null value it founds, or null if all of the values are null. The the previous query will return all rows where `Banana = @FruitInput` in case they are both non Null, or where they are both Null, which is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Fruit
WHERE (Banana = @FruitInput) OR (Banana IS NULL AND @FruitInput IS NULL)
```

You could also use an extension that allows for the comparison against null values:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
SELECT * FROM Fruit WHERE Banana = NULL;
```

but it's better to avoid using this feature in new development work since in future versions of SQL Server ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and changing its value would return an error.